# Subconsulta en SQL con multiples resultados: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sybase

Tengo en esta transaccion SQL un inconveniente cuando la subquery trae multiples resultados. Es decir cuando solo trae uno, funciona la aplicacion correctamente, sin embargo cuando arroja mas de un resultado, rompe y el error es:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is illegal when the subquery
> follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, or when the subquery is used as an
> expression.

El problema se encuentra en lo que debería agregar en el primer `WHERE`, pero no estoy logrando como hacerlo, ya que `WHERE EXISTS` no funciona.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.id "
            + "FROM Promociones p "
            + "INNER JOIN ProactivoSucursal ps ON ps.promocion.id = p.id AND p.fechaHasta >= GETDATE() AND psmt.fechaHastaSolicitada >= GETDATE() "
            + "INNER JOIN Sucursales s ON psmt.sucursales.id = s.id "
            + "INNER JOIN Comercios c ON s.comercios.id = c.id "
            + "WHERE (SELECT bc.pk.comercio.id FROM BeneficioComercio bc "
                + "INNER JOIN Beneficio b ON bc.pk.beneficio.id = b.id AND b.fechaHasta >= GETDATE() "
                + "WHERE b.promociones.id = ps.promociones.id) = NULL "
            + "AND :idPromociones = p.id"
            
            )
```

Comment: where exists no funciona? sobre que base de datos? escrito de que forma? si sabes cual es el error, porque lo estas aclarando, que podemos hacer por vos?

Comment: Hola Roger, no, WHERE Exists no funciona, rompe al levantar el server, con un error de tipo Incorrect node after Where...

Comment: Es Sybase la base y trabajo con hql de hibernate

Comment: Con el EXISTS me tira error unexpected AST node near line 1....

Comment: Roger, edito tu pregunta, las consutlas te las hago yo... Vuelvo a preguntar, si sabes que trae muchos registros, le falta algun where para que traiga uno solo.. o deberiamos ver el exists para ver como arreglarlo... si no, estamos tratando de adivinar....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues va a depender de lo que estés esperando, si la subconsulta da uno o más resultados con valores NULL, pues hacer que cuente las filas que son NULL y establecer la condición externa para que solo se cumpla cuando haya filas.

La subconsulta sería

```
SELECT COUNT(bc.pk.comercio.id) FROM BeneficioComercio bc "
 + "INNER JOIN Beneficio b ON bc.pk.beneficio.id = b.id AND b.fechaHasta >= GETDATE()"
 + " WHERE b.promociones.id = ps.promociones.id AND bc.pk.comercio.id IS NULL
```

Es decir, el número de registros que son nulos, luego a la consulta principal le dices que solo quieres los que tome el resultado cuando el resultado de la subconsulta sea mayor a 0.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.id "
            + "FROM Promociones p "
            + "INNER JOIN ProactivoSucursal ps ON ps.promocion.id = p.id AND p.fechaHasta >= GETDATE() AND psmt.fechaHastaSolicitada >= GETDATE() "
            + "INNER JOIN Sucursales s ON psmt.sucursales.id = s.id "
            + "INNER JOIN Comercios c ON s.comercios.id = c.id "
            + "WHERE (
                SELECT COUNT(bc.pk.comercio.id) FROM BeneficioComercio bc "
                + "INNER JOIN Beneficio b ON bc.pk.beneficio.id = b.id AND 
                  b.fechaHasta >= GETDATE() "
                + " WHERE b.promociones.id = ps.promociones.id AND bc.pk.comercio.id IS NULL) > 0"
            + "AND :idPromociones = p.id"
            
            )
```

Comment: Excelente! Mil gracias.